# Unable to sync google calendar after enabling the gmail integration in salesforce

Tags: calendar, google, lightning-for-gmail

I have enabled the Gmail Integration and sync in my salesforce and added the gmail salesforce chrome extension.

But I'm unable to sync my google calendar with salesforce calendar.
Can you anyone suggest me how to sync google calendar with salesforce calendar without using any apps.

Thanks.
[image: GI] [image: Inbox] [image: email tracking]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that without using that silly Google Extension.

You can easily navigate to

> Setup > Inbox > Setup Assistant (see my screenshot)

and then Activate :

1. Make Inbox Available to Users
2. Email Tracking

[image: Salesforce Inbox setup]

You also need to go `Setup > Gmail Integration And Lightning Sync`

and follow the screenshot below

[image: Gmail Integration And Lightning Sync]

Then go back to your Salesforce instance and go Calendar to see it synced (though it will take some time - be patient) [see screenshot]

[image: Salesforce Calendar]

For more information see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.inbox.htm&type=5 on other setups you want and other considerations to look out for.

Comment: Lightning sync is not available in my org.I have enabled the gmail integration and sync and enabled the make inbox available to user and email tracking. Please tell me why lightning sync is not showing in my org and how can I add image in the commend.

Comment: In my answer, I never mentioned anything about activating Lightning Sync. Even without Lightning Sync, I am able to get my Google Calendar synced to my Salesforce Calendar. You can only add image by editing your question and pressing the image function. Also do you mind marking my answer as helpful?

Comment: I have added the images in my question. Still I can't sync google calendar with salesforce. Is there any way to check google calendar is synced with salesforce?

Comment: @Lilly ok I updated my answer. You can see it works for me. If it still doesn't work for you I suggest you contact Salesforce Support ( https://help.salesforce.com/s/cases)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have one more doubt .In my org I have created Auth.Provide for lightning for gmail and assigned to my user profile .Will this cause any issue to sync google calendar?

Comment: Nope I'm also using Google Single Sign On (SSO). But note you have to fill up the federation identifier in the User Detail - ask another question for that. Btw since you found my answer helpful, could you tick my answer - this will help our reputation score.